# Отличие let/const от var

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Везде явно описывается лишь то, что в отличии от `var` - `let/const` обладают блочной областью видимости, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, интересно с чем связано:

```js
let App = App || {};

App.init = function() {
  console.log('Inited');
}

App.init(); // Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined (с const то же самое)
```

```js
var App = App || {};

App.init = function() {
  console.log('Inited');
}

App.init(); // 'Inited'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Берем и читаем стандарт.

Переменные Let и Const создаются в запущенном контексте и недоступны ровно до тех пор, пока не будут вычислены их значения при присваивании. Если же вычисления нет, то по умолчанию им присваивается undefined.

Переменные Var создаются в контексте и сразу же инициализируются значением undefined, только потом происходит их вычисление.

> 13.3 Declarations and the Variable Statement
>
> 13.3.1 Let and Const Declarations
>
> NOTE let and const declarations define variables that are scoped to
>   the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment. The variables are
>   created when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated **but
>   may not be accessed in any way until the variable’s LexicalBinding is
>   evaluated. A variable defined by a LexicalBinding with an Initializer
>   is assigned the value of its Initializer’s AssignmentExpression when
>   the LexicalBinding is evaluated, not when the variable is created.** If
>   a LexicalBinding in a let declaration does not have an Initializer the
>   variable is assigned the value undefined when the LexicalBinding is
>   evaluated.
>
> 13.3.2 Variable Statement
>
> NOTE A var statement declares variables that are scoped to the running
>   execution context’s VariableEnvironment. **Var variables are created
>   when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated and are
>   initialized to undefined when created.** Within the scope of any
>   VariableEnvironment a common BindingIdentifier may appear in more than
>   one VariableDeclaration but those declarations collective define only
>   one variable. A variable defined by a VariableDeclaration with an
>   Initializer is assigned the value of its Initializer’s
>   AssignmentExpression when the VariableDeclaration is executed, not
>   when the variable is created.

Comment: Во, вот так понятнее, что отличие именно в "очередности задания undefined". Но все же + за верный ответ уже отдал, не взыщи, просто плюсану за пояснение.

Comment: @MedvedevDev все нормально, я не переживаю по таким поводам и не гонюсь за рейтингом. Главное, что ответ был полезен.

Comment: @MedvedevDev Плюсану за тебя :) Почему нет

Comment: @Grundy, перелогиньтесь!

Answer (score 3):

Во втором случае App инициализирован и имеет undefined, а в первом случае у тебя ошибка в первой строке о неинициализированной переменной.

Comment: Это весь js который имеется.

Comment: Перед тем как выполнить код, js движок проходится и инициализирует переменные которые объявлены через var и проставляет им значение undefined.

Comment: То есть получается let и var отличаются не только зоной видимости, но и тем как работают (видимо var ищет присвоенные переменные и если не нашел, то задает undefined; а let просто ищет, но ничего не задает)? .... интересное кино.

Comment: Подводных камней в js очень много, поэтому лучше почитать соответствующую литературу.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let   https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var  Вот документация по var и let

Comment: Сколько читал информацию про let, везде говорится лишь про то, что обладает блочной видимостью, просто такие нюансы как-то нигде не видывал (ну или неверно интепретировал информацию), по этому и решил задать вопрос, а не просто оставить var. В этих статьях ничего похожего тоже не наблюдаю. Так же речь только про блочную область видимости.

Comment: Цитата:"Объявление переменной всегда обрабатывается до выполнения кода, где бы она ни находилась. " это по var

Comment: Сложно ... ладно, вроде понял отличие, благодарю.