# Что использовать var или let

Tags: javascript

Вот думаю что лучше использовать внутри функций, `var` или `let`?

Так как я использую компиляцию TypeScript то с поддержкой старых браузеров проблемы быть не должно в обоих вариантах.

Как я понял `let` более предпочтительный, так как он полностью локален в блоках и более предсказуем.

Но меня смущает использование let в циклах, так как для каждой итерации создаётся своя переменная. Зачем это делается я знаю, но беспокоюсь за съедание лишней памяти. Или это такая мелочь для большинства задач, что на эту тему париться не стоит? Ответы прошу аргументированные.

**PS:** это не дубликат вопроса ["Отличие let/const от var"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711027/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-let-const-%D0%BE%D1%82-var) потому что тот вопрос про конкретную ошибку в коде, а мой вопрос теоретический и более общий про использование данных конструкций. Кроме того я не спрашиваю про отличая, их я знаю, меня интересует что предпочтительнее использовать.

Comment: Приветствую! Насчёт циклов, если я правильно понимаю, в каждой новой итерации переменные созданные в прошлой итерации удалятся, т.к. на них больше не останется ссылок (если мы их никуда не записали конечно). garbage collection то есть

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отличие let/const от var](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711027/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-let-const-%d0%be%d1%82-var)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это не дубликат вопроса! Тот вопрос я читал и там вопрос про конкретную ошибку в коде, а мой вопрос ближе к теории и более общий.

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko спасибо, про это я что-то не подумал.

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko я вот подумал что да, они удалятся при проходе GC но то что они уже туда попали реально всё-же время отнимает. То есть цикл в 100 итераций, значит 100 переменных попали в GC.

Comment: к сожалению, я не знаю деталей работы gc, если я правильно понимаю, когда переменная (т.е. область памяти) более не имеет ссылок на себя, она очищается. наверное это сложнее.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин там не про ошибку в коде а именно описание отличия. также как и например в вопросе [Разница в поведении между let и var в цикле for](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/716243). Не вижу никакого крупного отличия и того, что не было бы сказано в тех ответах.....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я знаю в чём разница, мой вопрос о другом, что лучше использовать. Я добавил это в вопрос.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин что лучше использовать исходит из понимания разниц между ними. А разница указана))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, следует, но что бы эту связь проследить я и задал вопрос, так как результат не очевиден, покрайней мере для меня, но думаю что не только для меня.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин `я не спрашиваю про отличая, их я знаю, меня интересует что предпочтительнее использовать.` - ну смешно же)) я знаю разницу между самолётом и кораблём - но  меня интересует что предпочтительнее из этого использовать)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишу свой взгляд на `let` и `var`.

Конечно, `let` - некий *"новый синтаксический сахар"*. С ним могут возникать проблемы совместимости, но если это для вас не особо важно, то я бы использовал именно `let`. Мои аргументы:

1. Приведенная выше конструкция мне кажется просто ужасной:

   ```
   if (true) {
       var a = 2;
   }

   a = a + 2;
   ```

   В основном, с точки зрения читаемости. Человек, читающий ваш код, может часами искать объявление этой переменной. А раз эта конструкция ужасна, то единственное преимущество `var` - фигня.
2. Что касается циклов. Конечно, создается новая переменная... Но тогда, когда эта переменная уже не нужна, любой нормальный GC ее соберет. С той же `var` если вам нужно было сделать коллбэки в цикле, нужно было использовать дополнительную функцию, чтобы создать копию переменной. Что еще хуже.

Ну, пока что это все, что приходит на ум, но мне кажется, что этих причин достаточно. Единственное, на что вам нужно смотреть при выборе `let` или `var` - могут ли быть проблемы с совместимостью. Если нет - то смело используйте `let`.

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш ответ стал той последней каплей где я принял решение использовать let. Конечно почти большинство ответов - достойные, но отмечаю этот ответ ответом. Кстати я использую TypeScript, а для него `let` официально рекомендуем разработчиками http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html смотрим описание в самом конце, это было предпоследней каплей.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин ага. Если тайпскрипт, то тогда тем более, ведь используется транспилятор, так что проблем совместимости быть не может

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин главное в старом коде не начинать поголовно исправлять var на let .... https://tproger.ru/translations/es6-cheatsheet-1/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хорошая статья, спасибо, буду изучать, хоть большую часть я знаю, но уверен что-то найду полезное

Answer (score 2):

Отдаю предпочтение использованию `var`, все же более привычно и не возникает проблем с совместимостью. По мне переменные `let` представляют "синтаксический сахар", который минимизирует ошибки новичков при определении области видимости переменных (но это мое субъективное мнение, писать хороший код можно как используя `var`, так и `let`, а также их комбинации).

> Но меня смущает использование let в циклах, так как для каждой
>   итерации создаётся своя переменная. Зачем это делается я знаю, но
>   беспокоюсь за съедание лишней памяти. Или это такая мелочь для
>   большинства задач, что на эту тему париться не стоит?

Если у вас не огромные циклы с множественной вложенностью, то проблем быть не должно. Обычно в циклах перебора используются INT-переменные (4 байта). Далее сами можете посчитать сколько памяти съедает конкретный цикл. Если используются переменные других типов - смотрите сколько весят и подсчитываете по той же методике.

Answer (score 1):

> Как я понял let более предпочтительный, так как он полностью локален в блоках и более предсказуем.

Думаю, не всегда стоит считать это преимуществом. Приведу пример:

```
if (true) {
    var a = 2;
}

a = a + 2;
```

Как мне кажется (сугубо личное мнение, но, думаю, многие со мной согласятся), это выглядит намного приятнее, чем это:

```
let a;

if (true) {
    a = 2;
}

a = a + 2;
```

Так что лично я считаю, что ограничение области видимости переменной, объявленной при помощи `let` в блок - это притянутое за уши преимущество. Не всегда это особенно удобно.

С другой стороны да, отсутствие hoisting'а вряд ли можно назвать недостатком [*см. комментарии*].

> Но меня смущает использование let в циклах, так как для каждой итерации создаётся своя переменная. Зачем это делается я знаю, но беспокоюсь за съедание лишней памяти.

GC. Переменная сохраняется в памяти до тех пор, пока до нее можно добраться из глобального объекта. Так что на этот счет, думаю, волноваться точно не стоит.

В целом, на этот вопрос нельзя дать конкретный ответ. Для одних задач лучше подходит `var`, для других - `let`. Если особо не вдаваться в подробности, то я бы использовал `let` с "вкраплениями" `var` в ситуациях вроде той, что я описал выше.

Comment: _отсутствие hoisting'а_ - на самом деле он не отсутствует

Comment: @Grundy разве ?

Comment: [да](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/641284/186999)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за ссылку. Тогда, думаю, можно сойтись на том, что они хойстятся, но "не так", как при использовании `var`.

Answer (score -1):

### [let vs var](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Когда let используется внутри блока, то область видимости переменной ограничивается этим блоком. Напомним, что отличие заключается в том, что областью видимости переменных, объявленных оператором var, является вся функция, в которой они были объявлены.

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;

if (a === 5) {
  let a = 4; // The scope is inside the if-block
  var b = 1; // The scope is inside the function

  console.log(a);  // 4
  console.log(b);  // 1
} 

console.log(a); // 5
console.log(b); // 1
```

### let в циклах

Вы можете использовать ключевое слово let для привязки переменных к локальной области видимости цикла for, вместо того что бы использовать глобальные переменные (объявленные с помощью var).

```js
for (let i = 0; i<10; i++) {
  console.log(i); // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ... 9
}

console.log(i); // i is not defined
```

P.S. [for js FF](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: `Цикл for не создает новую переменную при каждой итерации, а всего лишь присваивает ей новое значение.` как раз таки нет, читаем пункт 3 - https://learn.javascript.ru/let-const

Comment: @Дмитрий Полянин  Не верю, если бы создавалась переменная каждый раз то выдало бы `SyntaxError`, делаю логический вывод что переменная в цикле `for` меняет значение. Думаю вы неправильные выводы сделали читаю ту статью.

Comment: @АлексТвояТруба Там же приведен четкий пример с замыканием, который показывает, что переменные таки разные

Comment: @АлексТвояТруба, в [спецификации для For](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-forbodyevaluation) явно вызывается создание **нового** environment и создании в нем **новых** биндингов с теми же именами на каждой итерации

Comment: @Grundy, не совсем понял. В JS еще путаюсь. То есть в цикле `for(let i=0;i<10;i++) { //переменная i будет иметь новый адрес в памяти при каждой итерации;}`

Comment: @АлексТвояТруба, на самом деле как это будет фактически реализовано нужно смотреть непосредственно в коде (например V8), но в терминах спецификации - да

Comment: @АлексТвояТруба лучше убрать концовку вашего ответа после PS

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин вы правы стоит. Да уж не ожидал от цикла в JS такого поведения. А вот интересно если const ссылку предать? `for(const a={r:5, i:0}; a.i<10; a.i++){console.log(a.i)}` то по логике константа тоже будет иметь новый адрес в памяти при каждой итерации цикла for.

Comment: @АлексТвояТруба, нет не будет. так как это константа, а на каждой итерации инициализируются только переменные объявленные через `let`: [If isConst is false, let perIterationLets be boundNames; otherwise let perIterationLets be « ».](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-for-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation)